# URL without domain Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Please how can I have URLs like :

```
 <a href="/auth/register">Signup</a>
```

instead of :

```
 <a href="http://domain.tld/auth/register">Signup</a>
```

in Laravel 4? And which is the best for SEO ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use `URL::route()` or `URL::action()` then you can generate `relative` urls because those functions accept an `absolute/Boolean` parameter, for example check the `route` method in `URL` class:

```
// route
public function route($name, $parameters = array(), $absolute = true, $route = null)
```

Or the `action` method:

```
// action
public function action($action, $parameters = array(), $absolute = true)
```

If you use these methods then you may generate relative urls using something like this:

```
URL::route('routename', array(), false) // requires a named route
URL::action('HomeController@getIndex', array(), false);
```

Here the third parameter `false` is being used to generate a relative url, by default it's `true`. For the second question [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) and [this article](https://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/) as well.

I prefer the default (absolute url) and `named route` always, so generating urls become easy by referencing the route name and it's easy to change any `url` without touching the code because named `routes` allow us to use the `route name` instead of the `url` to generate it.